# Why was this question closed and what should I do about it?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

[Where can I legally download Windows 8 for my OEM product? [closed]](https://superuser.com/questions/579822/where-can-i-legally-download-windows-8-for-my-oem-product)

The question was closed for being "off topic" or is not within the scope defined in the faq.

Let's review the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq#questions) shall we.

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
>   question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software, or
> - personal and home computer networking

It is indeed a question about two out of three above in which...

it is about hardware because it pertains to a problem unique to OEM computers pre-loaded with windows 8.

It is also about software because i'm looking for a solution about where I can find a piece of software.

And the question indeed is not about the following:

> - programming and software development,
> - video games or consoles,
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer,
> - issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,
> - asking for a shopping or product recommendation,

And I also believe that the question is practical, answerable, and is based on an actual problem that I face.

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

I find it even more questionable that my question is closed while all these other questions are not despite the similarity of the problem.

- [Where to find the Windows 8 ISO?](https://superuser.com/questions/496374/where-to-find-the-windows-8-iso)
- [Where can I get an installer for Windows 8 which can be activated
  with OEM (System builder) key? Maybe MSDN will work?](https://superuser.com/questions/572262/where-can-i-get-an-installer-for-windows-8-which-can-be-activated-with-oem-syst)
- [Where can I download Windows 8 legally, from Microsoft?](https://superuser.com/questions/493766/where-can-i-download-windows-8-legally-from-microsoft)

Comment: Thank you for finding those question. I have voted to close all of them.

Comment: @Nifle can you please answer why they're supposed to be closed and what can I do to improve the question to prevent this from happening again?

Comment: There really is nothing you can do. Not all questions have a place here on SU. And currently the consensus is that questions asking where to download things are off topic. Why? Well I think it's mainly because answers tend to get outdated fast.

Comment: For your question (and questions like it) the only rather unhelpful answer is: **Contact Microsoft or those that made your computer**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic reason that questions like this are closed is because they are not about a computer related problem. I agree that the FAQ is unclear, but when we say "computer related problems" we mean something along the lines of "I am trying to accomplish task X on my computer, how can I do this?". These are questions that can be answered by giving a specific solution, a way of achieving the requested task. Questions of the "Where can I find Y?" type, such as yours, are not the kind of computer problem this site deals with.

First of all, as Nifle said, answers will get outdated very very fast. Second, this is just not a computer problem really, it is more akin to a shopping request which is explicitly off topic. The difference between "Where can I download Y?" and "Where can I buy X?" is very very small. Third this really is something you should be asking Microsoft about, not us.

As proof that you are not being singled out, you will notice that all three questions you linked to are now closed. I'm not saying you are asking a bad question, it is just not in the scope of this site.

Comment: Okay, this is a very good answer. my kind of question in superuser basically cannot fulfill the "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." part of the requirement simply because though it is possible to answer the question, the answer will either be unhelpful or quickly be outdated. So now I have a new question, why is THIS question voted down?

Comment: @SubaruTashiro, votng in Meta is different to that of the main site: "voting is often used to express agreement or disagreement, not to point out a lack of quality or helpfulness". A down vote in meta means that people do not agree with your suggestion, it should not be taken personally and it does not mean there is anything wrong with your question (it also has no effect on your reputation). See [here](http://meta.superuser.com/faq#vote-differences). The downvotes you have received for this question mean that people feel your original question was closed correctly and should remain closed.

Comment: oh, i see, i thought that i needed to improve my meta question. Now I understand. I will be accepting this answer. Thanks everyone.